# Getting list of published apps from Google play store

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to have activity in my app where i show list of other apps that has been created and published by me to users, my question is:

Is that possible I get list of my published apps in Google Play Store and show them to users or I have to create custom activity and manually introduce my other apps in Play Store?

## Update

here is my fragment (activity code)

```
class ToolsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var toolsViewModel: ToolsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        toolsViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ToolsViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools, container, false)
        //val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_tools)
        //toolsViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        //    textView.text = it
        //})


        val i = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=0000000000000000000")
        )
        startActivity(i)
        return root
    }
}
```

This offers me to open link in browser when i click on my activity link, what i'm looking for is to show list of my apps inside my activity fragment and not to open web page in browser.

any idea on that?

Comment: You can wrap your developer page into a webactivity

Comment: @PaoloColombo hows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, I haven't found any `api` to get published app list in Google play..
However, I've tried to build a **scraper** to get the list for you, but it fails in first place, maybe google redirects to login/sign in page after a few `http` calls, for example with url: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=0000000000000000000`. Tried with: `openConnection()` of `URL` class & `Jsoup`.

The idea was to **scrape** the body and get the app name, img & url. Then we would be able to set it in a recycler view.

:(

**Edit:**
Just as a workaround..
You can set up a `WebViewClient` within the activity/fragment to load the apps from your `More by developer` page.

```
 val webview: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview) // or just use synthetic
 val myUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=WhatsApp+Inc."
 webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
 webview.loadUrl(myUrl)
```

View:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image: More by google]

Comment: thanks man, i tried it but `webview` is red and there is nothing for import. how should i fix this error before i can test your solution?

Comment: @mafortis I was using synthetic, updated answer, check if it full fill your purpose..

Comment: it doesn't load anything in my view is just white page `screenshot` https://ibb.co/kgvdzZx

Comment: didn't you add `internet permission`?

Comment: here is my code (screenshot) maybe i did something wrong https://ibb.co/NSzyFG7

Comment: could you please post your fragments code in your answer or link of code, I can modify that..

first you're not using webview that you've created (variable) 
and you should  load webview once view is created, in your fragments `onViewCreated()` callback

Comment: i see, i was using  `webview?.` while i should have refer to `var`

Comment: you may have opinion on this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198871/how-to-get-listpreference-value-in-kotlin-activity :)

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ and __scrape__ not scrapper or scrap

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your developer page in play console (settings->developer page) and then you can call it with Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=8408908814286885702"));
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: @mafortis yes, in that page all your applications published on PlayStore will be show

Comment: Maybe you can scrap your elements from the web page or you can use a web view that show a web page in your application without call a browser